# Weird behaviour while inspecting chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have a script running by click on extension icon - it should grab tab URL, post it to remote server, get some list as response. For some websites, everything is working just fine, but for some other - it only displays first line, it is, "URL: blabla.com" (It is still posting correctly). Now, when I try to debug it - right-click, inspect element and I get my list (it doesnt display line with "URL:" though).

Now my question - why?

code:

```
 chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
   var tablink = tab.url;
    document.write("<p>"+ "URL: "+ tablink +"</p>");
    document.write("<p>"+ "Lists: </p>");
    var myData = { url: tablink };
    $.ajax(
            {
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/addon/',
            type: "post",
            data: myData,
            success: function(response){

            document.write("<p>"+ "Response: "+ response.id +"</p>");
                ...
```

**edit** : i fixed this problem by using .append() instead of document.write(), but question is still valid for further reference - why and how "inspect element" differs from regular popup-opening click...